# Where's repository of debbuild scripts?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Needless to say, `http://www.ros.org/debbuild/$ROS_DISTRO$.html` (eg. [hydro](http://www.ros.org/debbuild/hydro.html)) pages are quite useful for release fans!

I just can't find its repository and issue trackers. Where is it?

---

In concrete for `debbuild` web site, I stopped being able to show the search result by reloading the page with the search query left in the textfield; the page used to show the search result after reloading. Maybe these few days, it shows blank search result area.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/103516/where%27s-repository-of-debbuild-scripts?/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2013-11-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The scripts you're asking about can be found here: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/buildfarm/tree/master/scripts

Note there's a newer version at https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/ros_buildfarm/tree/master/scripts/status

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2016-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0